# Where is the issue in this trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need your expert observation to make this trigger work.

I have 3 tables, `Create_Event` is main, 2nd (`events_status`) is status table and 3rd (`event_history`) one is 'backup table'.

I just want to keep a track of every events as the status is updated to 'Completed' also want to delete the same row from the Main table but I don't want to lose it until I have a track.

So, here is that what I am trying..but its delete part is not working.

```
ALTER TRIGGER trgUpdhistory on Events_Status for update    
as  
declare @status varchar(255)  
BEGIN  
set xact_abort on  
    select @status=status from inserted  

if (@status = 'Completed')          
    begin  try        
    begin tran   

 insert into Event_History          
 select * from Create_Event          
 where exists(select * from create_event D left join inserted E on D.ID=E.CE_Ids)        

 delete from Create_Event  
 where exists(select * from create_event D left join deleted E on D.ID=E.CE_Ids)  
COMMIT  
end try          

begin catch    
    ROLLBACK  
    RAISERROR ('Transaction is not completed',16,1)         
end catch           

END
```

Comment: "*the* issue"? I can see several. `inserted` can contain multiple rows so what do you expect `@status` will be set to? Also, `exists` checks with `left join`s back to the trigger tables and no attempt to correlate the subqueries to the tables in the outer query.

Comment: i believe where condition is also messing it up it should be something like delete from Create_Event  
 where ID in (select ID from create_event D left join deleted E on D.ID=E.CE_Ids)

Comment: @RAHULSR - that's one approach to fixing the correlation issue but so long as we still have that `left join` and no `where` clause, it's still going to pull *every* row from `create_event`.

Comment: This trigger runs on `UPDATE`, yet seems to be designed to do things based on the existence of rows in `INSERTED` and `DELETED` pseudo tables (On update they'll exist in both!). Should it not run on insert and delete to `Events_Status` as well, or do you have other triggers for those?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever  ya thats why i said "also" since you did mentioned that earlier  i believe he should do something  select top 1@status=status from inserted  order by id desc i am not sure though

Comment: Thanks for your observation guys.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever,@Rahul S R 
@status=status(column_name). As you said I gave the WHERE condition and also tried as you mentioned but still it is not working. Is there any alternate way to perform this query but only through trigger?

Comment: @Bridge I want to perform `insert and delete` operation in other two tables by `updating` 2nd table in single trigger.